# Select first in and last out time from SQL Table quires required

Tags: sql

I have a database table with below mentioned fields
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Createtime| |Department| |DeviceId| |DeviceName| |UserCode|
|UserName|   |DataPostingDateTime|      |RowID|

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|04-06-2022 18:33:00||ADMINISTRATION||7101550000000||SECOND GATE||DM00010||ASHUTOSH SHARMA||Jun  4 2022  6:34PM||2354|

and i need to retrieve data in below mentioned format

**|Reference ID||Created Time||Employee Code||Punch Date||Punch Time||Punch Type|**

```
  Reference Id = "Row id"
  Created Time = "DataPostingDateTime"
  Punch Type= "IN  or OUT "
```

Comment: Using the example row you provided - how do you know what the PUNCH TYPE is ?

Comment: Please, make your question more understandable. Read help on asking questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask